# Can not properly create a main layout with nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm new to React and Next and what I'm trying to do is to wrap my main contents within a layout that will be shared along my pages.

In my components folder I created a Layout.js file:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

import Header from './main/Header';
import Footer from './main/Footer';

import '../styles/main.scss';

const Layout = (props) => (
  <div>
    <Head>
      <title>Testing</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/style.css" />
    </Head>
    <div className="app">
      <Header />
      {props.children}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default Layout;
```

And I'm using it in my index.js file within the pages folder:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Layout from '../components/Layout';

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
};
```

The result is this error:

> React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

I bet there is something wrong I did in my Layout.js file, but I can not understand how to exactly fix that. I hope you can help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why are you add

```
    <Head>
      <title>Testing</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_next/static/style.css" />
    </Head>`
```

In your `Layout` component ? I think the head tag should be in `pages/_document.js`.
See my [repository](https://github.com/snettah/nextjs-ant-styled) it's work fine for me

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment. It helped me to improve my app but the issue was inside my `Header` where I used `Link` without the `a` within.

Comment: That's what I thought

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of Next.js:

> Note: React-components outside of <Main /> will not be initialised by the browser.

So you have to override the default App component.
To override, create the `./pages/_app.js` and put this inside. You have to adapt imports of modules.

```
import React from 'react'
import App, {Container} from 'next/app'
import Layout from '../components/Layout'
import Header from '../components/main/Header'
import Footer from '../components/main/Footer'

export default class MyApp extends App {
  render () {
    const {Component, pageProps} = this.props
    return (
      <Container>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
          </Layout>
        <Footer />
        </Container>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```